# Create Webservice using Visual Studio Express 2012

Tags: web-services, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-express

I have Visual Studio Express 2012 for Desktop installed on my machine. I now want to create a web service. Should I download full Visual Studio Express 2012 for web or are there any templates or patches which I can add in the Desktop version only to create a web service